# how to make a menuitem in odoo module

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to implement a view for a custom module in odoo
the module is called "test" and it had 1 model called "room"

when i click on the menu i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
raise value
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1262, in load
action = request.env[action_type].browse([action_id]).read()
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 210, in read
result = super(IrActionsActWindow, self).read(fields, load=load)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2797, in read
vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5123, in __getitem__
return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 985, in __get__
self.determine_value(record)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1098, in determine_value
self.compute_value(recs)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1052, in compute_value
self._compute_value(records)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1043, in _compute_value
getattr(records, self.compute)()
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py", line 170, in _compute_search_view
fvg = self.env[act.res_model].fields_view_get(act.search_view_id.id, 'search')
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1455, in fields_view_get
result = self._fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1428, in _fields_view_get
arch_etree = getattr(self, '_get_default_%s_view' % view_type)()
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1258, in _get_default_search_view
return E.search(element, string=self._description)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lxml/builder.py", line 218, in __call__
get(dict)(elem, attrib)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lxml/builder.py", line 205, in add_dict
attrib[k] = typemap[type(v)](None, v)
KeyError: <class 'bool'>
```

here is my XML file:

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="test.listtt">
      <field name="name">room list</field>
      <field name="model">test.room</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="name"/>
          <field name="rating"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>


    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="test.action_window">
      <field name="name">room window</field>
      <field name="res_model">test.room</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
      <field name="view_type">form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem name="test"   id="test.menu_root"  action="test.action_window"/>

  </data>
</odoo>
```

it seems that the action is not properly linked to my model view
i guess maybe the ids i provided are wrong or something

Comment: If you are using `openerp7` you should see the following error in the log `Invalid XML: A 'tree' must have 'string' attribute and an immediate node of 'tree' view must be 'field' or 'button'.`

Comment: @Nada, Please post the python code too.